# Properties of chromatic number

Tags: graph-theory

Definitions:

1. The independence number $\alpha(G)$ is the maximum size of an independent set of $G$.
2. A coloring of $G$ is a partition of the vertices into (induced) independent sets (colors),
   and the chromatic number $\chi(G)$ is the smallest number of colors possible in a coloring of $G$.

> What is the relation between $\chi(\bar{G})$ and $\alpha(G)$ for any
>   graph?, where $\bar G$ is complement of $G$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you take the complement, an independent set becomes a clique. Hence in $\bar{G}$, there is a $K_{\alpha (G)}$ subgraph.

It is known that you can not color a clique of size $k$ with less than $k$ colors, thus
$$
\chi(\bar{G}) \geq \alpha (G). 
$$

Comment: If $G$ is a circle of $n$ points, $\alpha(G) = n-1$ and $\bar{G}$ is a $K_n$ without a circle. You can color $\bar{G}$ with $n-1$ colors since you can choose the same color for the end vertices of an arbitrary edge of  $G$.

Comment: Unfortunately I didn't think about more examples, where the equality holds. For sure it doesn't hold for any graph since if $\bar{G}$ is an odd cycle, $\alpha (G)=2$ but $\chi (\bar{G}) = 3$.

Is the proof and this example clear for you?

Comment: In fact equality holds if and only if the clique number of $\bar{G}$ is equal to the chromatic number of $\bar{G}$, maybe you can find some tables online which list these numbers for well known graphs.